# Where do I add a new cache context for an entity?

Tags: 8, caching

I have not been able to get adding a cache context to work for entities in drupal 8.  Specifically I'm going for headers:User-Agent. I tried many variations on the following in a module.

```
 use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
 use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
 use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;

 function hook_entity_view_alter(&$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display){
   if($entity->getType() == 'relevant_type'){
    $build['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'headers:User-Agent';
   }

 }
```

I'm trying to get node access to be checked when that context changes. I have also tried it in the `hook_entity_build_defaults_alter()` function.

Comment: Notice that cache context don't influence the node access a user has. Cache context is just to change when data is cached.

Comment: The node access as set in hook_node_access is cached.

Comment: That is a different cache bin, not the one used for the content.

Comment: See classes that implement the \Drupal\Core\Cache\Context\CacheContextInterface

Answer (score 8):

You should indeed use [`hook_entity_build_defaults_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_build_defaults_alter/8). Its documentation even explicitly states this:

> Alter entity renderable values before cache checking in drupal_render().
>
> The values in the `#cache` key of the renderable array are used to determine if a cache entry exists for the entity's rendered output. Ideally only values that pertain to caching should be altered in this hook.

It probably didn't work for you because you forgot to clear the render cache after implementing that hook.

That hook is invoked in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilder.php/class/EntityViewBuilder/8

Also see https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/contexts for an overview of cache contexts (what they are, how to use them, which ones core ships with).